# How to find Active Directory group email address using AD group name in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, active-directory

I have an Active Directory group with a name like `Stack Over Flow IT`. Need to find AD group email like `stackoverflowit@stackoverflow.com`. No need to find AD user list.

How to find AD group email address?

Or how to find AD group name using AD group email address?

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");
```

I'm unable to find Active Directory group email address using the above `group` instance code.

Comment: If a answer solves your problem mark it as accepted answer. If it helps you give it a upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Mail of group

You can do the following:

```cs
PropertyValueCollection email = ((DirectoryEntry) group.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties["mail"];
```

If you have [RSAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools) available you can validate your code (in powershell) with:

```
get-adgroup -Identity "Stack Over Flow IT" -properties mail | select name,mail | sort mail
```

## Find Group via mail

Here is the reverse way for completeness:

```cs
// replace stuff inside [] to match your environment
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=[YOUR DC]", [username], [password], AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

DirectorySearcher groupSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);
groupSearcher.Filter = "(mail=stackoverflowit@stackoverflow.com)";
groupSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

foreach (SearchResult groupSr in groupSearcher.FindAll())
{
    ResultPropertyValueCollection groupName = groupSr.Properties["name"];
    // do something with finding
}
```